# How to redraw grid of widgets in flutter.io after receiving new items from network?

Tags: android, ios, user-interface, dart, flutter

I'm modifying Pesto example https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/76844e25da8806a3ece803f0e59420425e28a405/examples/flutter_gallery/lib/demo/pesto_demo.dart to receive new recipes from the net, by adding the following function:

```
  void loadMore(BuildContext context, query) {
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    client.getUrl(Uri.parse("http://10.0.2.2:5000/search/" + query ))
        .then((HttpClientRequest request) {
      return request.close();
    })
        .then((HttpClientResponse response) {
      // Process the response.
      response.transform(UTF8.decoder).listen((contents) {
        // handle data
        var decoded = JSON.decode(contents);
        var rec = new Recipe(
            name: decoded['title'],
            author: decoded['author'],
            professionIconPath: 'images/1.png',
            description: decoded['description'],
            imageUrl: 'http://example.jpg',
        );
        kPestoRecipes.add(job);
        //Navigator.push(context, new MaterialPageRoute<Null>(
        //    settings: const RouteSettings(name: "/"),
        //    builder: (BuildContext context) => new PestoHome(),
        //));
      });
    });
  }
```

and I binded loading additional recipe to clicking interface button:

```
floatingActionButton: new FloatingActionButton(
                child: new Icon(Icons.edit),
                onPressed: () {
                  scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(new SnackBar(
                      content: new Text('Adding new recipe')
                  ));
                  loadMore(context, "test");
                },
            ),
```

But how do I redraw home page when new recipe received? I've tried to 
the part with Navigator you've seen commented out, but it didn't work. I also tried

```
new PestoDemo();
```

but it showed new recipe only for a moment and didn't feel like a proper way to do re-drawing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should call setState whenever you change data that affects what the build() function for a given State object returns:

https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/State/setState.html

For example:

```
setState(() {
  _recipes.add(job);
});
```

If you do this, I'd recommend changing kPestoRecipes from being a global constant to being a private member variable of a State subclass.  That will probably involve passing the list around from one widget to another rather than having all the widget refer to the global constant.

One other tip: when you get the HttpClientResponse, you should check the `mounted` property of the State object.  If `mounted` is false, that means the widget has been removed from the tree and you might want to ignore the network response.